# Word meaning "assigning appropriate jobs to people" in an organization?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm wondering whether there's a word that basically means "finding out what people are good at and assigning them appropriate roles in an organization".  So determining that one person's a natural leader and making them the leader, someone else is good with people and they're the counselor, someone else is good technically and they're running the website, etc.

In medicine, there's the term "triage" which is kind of doing this but with patients and severity of their illness.

Comment: This is perhaps one of the best _SWR_'s I've seen, but I think you've hit upon a lexical gap. The nearest terms I've been able to find are the strong collocations (perhaps compound nouns) _functional assessment_, _vocational assessment_ and _aptitude testing_, but these only imply (rather than denote) subsequent provision of a position. These terms are defined at [Springer._Encyclopedia of Behavioral Medicine](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007%2F978-1-4419-1005-9_880), though they may have slightly different definitions conferred by other ...

Comment: institutions. 'Making the best use of manpower' is perhaps the standard expression.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Or "fitting square pegs in square holes - round pegs in round holes" is the business metaphor.

Comment: @WS2 Fascinatingly, [Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Square+Pegs)  gives the examples  'This is in addition to enabling the Administration to effectively place square pegs in square holes, as well as round pegs in round holes' ... Biometric capturing not to witch-hunt any staff a FCTA' **and** 'That alone lies with the board – square pegs and round holes is literally how Everton have shaped up for near on two seasons.' under 'References in classic literature'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few single words came to mind

> - appoint
> - choose
> - elect
> - nominate
> - delegate

I know you are asking for a word but what about

> Talent Management

Comment: I like 'talent management'.

Answer (score 1):

Since the asker seems to be highly skilled in linguistics, the  words I proffer might not interest him. But it can be useful for some others.

1. When an employer wants to assign appropriate people to the duties they would be good at, he should sift out "ashes from cinders".
   Why not use "sift out"?
2. Every employer shall see about interviewing or testing candidates so as to separate them according to their skills, personality, aptitudes, etc. In other words: "He shall see about the initial screening of candidates for the job.
   Why not use "screen"?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of **allocate** which means

> distribute (resources or duties) for a particular purpose.

So the usage could be like this.

> Allocate roles according to skills.

Answer (score 0):

to **apportion**  [TDF](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/apportion)

> To divide and assign according to a plan; allot:

*The jobs were **apportioned** according to each employee's skills.*